# Discard Changes in Design View

Tags: ssms

## Abstract

In SQL Server Management Studio, is it possible to discard changes in the Design view?

Right now, the least invasive solution I have found is to close and reopen the connection. This is still a very invasive solution because it closes all tabs.

## Reproduce

An example will explain the situation more clearly.

1. Right click a table in the Object Explorer.
2. Select "Design".
3. Change something (e.g., the Data Type of one of the columns).
4. Do not save.
5. Close the tab (and do not save it).
6. Right click the table in the Object Explorer again.
7. Select "Design" again.
8. The previously unsaved changes are re-opened.

## Desired Outcome

In step #8, I would like the table's current properties to be shown, not the unsaved changes made previously in a different tab. If I explicitly choose to close a tab without saving it and then open up a new tab, SSMS should open up a new tab, not restore the tab I already told it to discard.

## Additional Comments

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v18.1.

Comment: Same issue on SSMS 18.4, according to the docs this shouldn't happen

Comment: Same issue on 17.9.1

Comment: Same issue 17.9.1